# Can I have a file with variable content?

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to have a file with variable content? (It's probably not possible but worth asking as other might know a solution.)

For example the content of file **mydate.txt** should always be what this bash (it can be any scripting language, used bash just for simplicity) snippet produce:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
date
```

So when I try to see the content of the mydate.txt file it should actually display current date.

For example

```bash
cat mydate.txt
```

should display

```
Fri Dec 23 09:54:05 AM EET 2022
```

Comment: No, the bytes in an actual file are actual bytes. You can create a FIFO which produces a new line every time someone reads from it, but that's not technically really a file, and requires for there to be a process running which writes new data into the FIFO for its consumers to read.

Comment: You could create a special device file: Here's a [tutorial](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/195-simple-driver-for-linux-os) for linux if that's what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The given example and description looks (to me) like a (simple) wrapper function to execute the provided file ...  ***if*** the file has execute permissions enabled:

```
mycat() { for fname in "$@"; do ./"${fname}"; done; }
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ mycat mydate.txt
Fri Dec 23 11:02:20 CST 2022

$ mycat mydate.txt mydate.txt mydate.txt
Fri Dec 23 11:21:07 CST 2022
Fri Dec 23 11:21:07 CST 2022
Fri Dec 23 11:21:07 CST 2022
```

**NOTES:**

- if the file has not been marked as executable it gets (quite) a bit more complicated (eg, sourcing a file bypasses any shebang that may be needed for the contents of the script to 'run' correctly; do you have permission to (re)set the 'execute' bit?)
- while this 'works' for the (relatively) simple example, I'm guessing it probably won't work in all of OP's scenarios in which case we'd need a more detailed problem description (and more examples)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the best answer is to use a FIFO (First In, First Out) file, maybe like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -f "catme.txt" ] && rm catme.txt    # cleanup if needed
mkfifo catme.txt

trap 'rm catme.txt ; exit 1' SIGINT.  # try to clean up the nice way

while true
do
    date > catme.txt
    printf "data provided on %s\n" "`date`"
done
```

run the command and use control-c to exit it. Then in another terminal you would call `cat catme.txt` and you will see our current date. This may not be what you want, but you have to attach a process to something dynamic in unix, else you can try running the command from your other script.